# Windows 10 - Disable/Extend time to enter username and password

Tags: windows-10, login, credentials

I've been looking around for a way to either disable or extend the amount of time a user gets when they try to enter in their username and password to login before the screen jumps back to the lock screen. This has been an annoyance since our users are not entering their credentials fast enough before it goes back to the lock screen and they have to click "Other User" and re-enter in the username and password.

Is this a possible setting to change?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.howtogeek.com/267893/how-to-change-the-windows-10-lock-screen-timeout/) explains exactly how to do it.

It's pretty straightforward and, once it is done, you just use "Power Options" to adjust the time.